# Wordpress inside Laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have wordpress inside my laravel application. My complete application is using laravel except blog. Now I want to handle a page through laravel but blog is coming before it.

Now,
http://tauriel.local/blog/test

Expected,
http://tauriel.local/test

My whole blog is inside blog folder. How can I remove blog from my wordpress page?

Comment: Then simply exclude the blog folder in .htaccess

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `blog` folder in your .htaccess

I believe that you have the wordpress content inside the folder `blog`

```
RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]
```

i.e.,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteRule ^(blog)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In which htaccess I should update code? Laravel's htaccess or wordpress' htaccess?

Comment: @IqbalMalik Convey once you done or facing any issues

Comment: I'd put the first RewriteRule (you added) after the RewriteEngine line, so that it will work if RewriteEngine is not on by default.

Comment: @Luceos If you think it was better, you shall edit my answer ;)